# Remove Order in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have 4 entities:

**Profile** which has a relation with companyContract:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "profile", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
private List<CompanyContract> companyContracts;
```

**CompanyContract** which has a relation with timesheet:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyContract", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
private List<Timesheet> timesheets;

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IDPROFILE")
private Profile profile;
```

**Timesheet** which has a relation with invoice:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "timesheet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
private List<Invoice> invoices;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IDCONTRACT")
private CompanyContract companyContract;
```

**Invoice:**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_TIMESHEET")
private Timesheet timesheet;
```

So As you can see here, I'm using *org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN* so I can delete the children of a parent.

If I execute this:

```
Profile p = companyContract.getProfile();
p.getCompanyContracts().remove(companyContract);
companyContract.setProfile(null);
profileService.update(p);
```

---> The order of removal should be:

Remove invoices --> Timesheets --> CompanyContract, No ?

And instead I'm getting this error:

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'IDCONTRACT' cannot be null

And I've checked, this error happens after `profileService.updateProfile(p);`

Comment: Have you tried to set `nullable=false` on the `@JoinColumn`, and `optional=false` on the `@ManyToOne` ? This might prevent a first update to null, followed by a delete

Comment: Actually I didn't but could you explain to me how those changes will prevent what you said cause that's exactly my problem

Comment: Do you need the `@ManyToOne` annotations?  It is not normally necessary to specify the target entity explicitly since it can usually be inferred from the type of the object being referenced. Just a thought.

Comment: Anyway, yea, you can't just set `profile` to `null`.

Comment: those attributes of `@JoinColumn` and `@ManyToOne` just constraint a bit more the mapping, and might make hibernate make the right decision when producing the sql queries.

Comment: @KarlNicholas the OP wants exactly the opposite of what you linked as duplicate.

Comment: @KarlNicholas, then how should I porceed ?

Comment: Well, it's kind of a guess without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, but it seems to me you are having trouble figuring out how to delete child entities. Perhaps a tutorial would help: https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/. Bottom line is this is not a minimum-verifiable-example but rather you seem to be having a problem getting your program to work. I sympathize, but it might be better if you stepped back a bit and worked out the issues on a simpler piece of code first.

Comment: Actually what i'm trying to do is that : I have a profile that contains companyContracts and companyContract contains timesheets, I want to when I remove a companyContract it gets deleted from the profile and delete all related timesheets

Comment: Just to be sure... those are the only entities or there are others maybe connected somehow and you missed the cascade?
P.s. why are you mixing jpa and hibernate cascade?

Comment: There are other entities but the problem is coming from the ones I mentionned

Comment: I'm mixing just for the 'Save_Update' cascade cause without it my code does'nt work

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid Please let me know If my answer has helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the column `IDCONTRACT`in the table that holds Timesheets has a `NOT NULL` restriction. Remove it and try again.

If you're autogenerating the schema, try adding `@Basic(optional = true)` to Timesheet.companyContract:

```
@Basic(optional = true)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IDCONTRACT")
private CompanyContract companyContract;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working completely fine. I see all associated child entities getting successfully deleted.

Check the below code.

Use orphanRemoval = true like below instead of deprecated way
`org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` , which you are using.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyContract", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Find code below

```
public void check() {

    System.out.println("Start check() in DummyDAOImpl");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    CompanyContract companyContract = session.get(CompanyContract.class, 2);
    Profile p = companyContract.getProfile();
    p.getCompanyContracts().remove(companyContract);
    companyContract.setProfile(null);
    session.update(p);

    session.flush();
    session.close();

    System.out.println("Executed check() in DummyDAOImpl");

}
```